# Looping a list and create dictionary based on the index

Tags: python

I would like to create a dictionary to get the output as follow:

Code:

```
d = {}
a = [[["man", "eater", "king"], ["king", "kong", "yes"]]]

for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for ii, xx in enumerate(x):
#this part i hope to check both the i and ii combination already inside the dictionary or not
#Example like if i or ii in d: # maybe something relevant
        d[i] = {ii:xx}
print(d)
```

Current output:

```
{0: {1: ['king', 'kong', 'yes']}}
```

Expected output:

```
{{0: {0: ['man', 'eater', 'king']}},{0: {1: ['king', 'kong', 'yes']}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
d = {i: {j: s for j, s in enumerate(l)} for i, l in enumerate(a)}
```

or with nested `for` loops:

```
d = {}
for i, l in enumerate(a):
    t = {}
    for j, s in enumerate(l):
        t[j] = s
    d[i] = t
```

`d` becomes:

```
{0: {0: ['man', 'eater', 'king'], 1: ['king', 'kong', 'yes']}}
```

Note that your expected output is incorrect because it is a set of dicts, which can't happen since dicts are unhashable.

Comment: I see. But is it possible to code it not in list comprehension form please

Comment: everything that is in list comprehension form can be unfolded and turn into for loops.

Comment: @Beginner I've updated my answer with a solution not using list comprehension then.

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
a = [[["man", "eater", "king"], ["king", "kong", "yes"]]]

for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for ii, xx in enumerate(x):
        d[i][ii] = xx
print(d)
```

---

or

```
d = {}
a = [[["man", "eater", "king"], ["king", "kong", "yes"]]]

for i, x in enumerate(a):
    d[i] = {}
    for ii, xx in enumerate(x):
        d[i][ii] = xx
print(d)
```

---

or

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for ii, xx in enumerate(x):
        d.setdefault(i, {})[ii] = xx
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0: {0: ['man', 'eater', 'king'], 1: ['king', 'kong', 'yes']}})
```